# How can I add an SVG to a Toggle Button?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, toggleswitch

I have a ToggleButton component that I'm using in multiple places.  For one of its uses, I would like an SVG to be rendered as the part of the toggle button that slides (if you look at the example located in the link in the comments, I'm referring to the circle part).

Here is my code for the component:

```
const ToggleButton = ({
  label,
  value,
  name,
  onChange,
}) => (
    <div className={styles.toggleButton}>
      <input
        id={name}
        type="checkbox"
        className={styles.checkbox}
        value={value}
        checked={value ? 'checked' : null}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <label htmlFor={name} className={styles.switch} />
    </div>
  );

export default ToggleButton;
```

Here is the CSS file:

```
.toggleButton {
  align-items: center;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.switch::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: gray;
  top: -4px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:checked + .switch::after {
  left: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.checkbox:checked + .switch {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: [link](https://i1.wp.com/reactscript.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Accessible-Toggle-Switch-Component-For-React.png?fit=541%2C370&ssl=1)

Comment: Just make a css rule for exaple a background of a div, scale it and add the div to yur button. Works exactly like any other image. Fontawesome converts the scg to base64 and use it as charcter. Take a lokk there :)

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>demo</title>
    <style>
    .ease {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #8a8a8a;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #8a8a8a;  
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  background-color: #f3c93c; 
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml; utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='15' height='15' viewBox='0 0 15 15'><path fill-rule='evenodd' d='M7.5.469c.9 0 1.629.754 1.629 1.675 0 .22-.048.443-.138.654l-.028.059.114.04c.765.278 1.456.76 1.992 1.387l.13.16.116.153c.56.784.885 1.732.926 2.7l.004.207v3.685h.451c.277 0 .51.199.57.462l.011.067.004.07c0 .305-.226.56-.517.594l-.068.004H9.641v.06c-.058 1.08-.87 1.957-1.907 2.072l-.116.01-.118.003c-1.141 0-2.079-.927-2.14-2.084l-.002-.06H2.311c-.278 0-.514-.2-.576-.463l-.012-.067-.004-.07c0-.304.231-.559.524-.594l.068-.004h.45l.001-3.685c0-.9.248-1.792.705-2.562l.109-.175.116-.17c.562-.78 1.35-1.378 2.234-1.7l.113-.038-.03-.066c-.05-.127-.087-.257-.109-.388l-.016-.13-.005-.131c0-.92.727-1.675 1.621-1.675zm.97 11.917H6.53v.031c.043.482.416.862.882.906l.088.004c.261 0 .506-.103.688-.292.157-.162.257-.383.28-.611l.002-.038zm-2.748-8.08c-1.06.63-1.734 1.785-1.786 3.04l-.004.158v3.685h7.136V7.504c0-1.266-.628-2.444-1.652-3.117l-.13-.081c-1.106-.652-2.474-.654-3.564 0zm1.614-2.603c-.177.08-.287.248-.287.44 0 .262.202.471.451.471.188 0 .35-.11.42-.284.07-.18.032-.388-.096-.52-.133-.137-.322-.176-.488-.107z'/></svg>");
  margin:auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}


input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #f3c93c;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <label class="switch" v-if="option.icon && option.icon === 'mute'">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked="true"            
          />      
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>       
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score -1):

Some examples:

```
         <style>
            .icon {
                background-color: orange;
                border: 1px solid blue;
                color: rgb(255, 0, 0) !important;
                background-image: linear-gradient(orange, orange, orange) !important;
                opacity: 1;
            }
       </style>
```

[data] means a base64 encoded string of the svg source
You may embed them in css

```
 <style>
 .logo {
      background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]");
      width:20px;
      height:20px;
 }
 </style>
```

as svg source inside the css

```
 <style>

     .svgbg { 
        width:100%; height:150px; 
       background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg 
       xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 44' height='44' 
        width='100'><path d='m 0,11 100,0' style='stroke:#efefef;stroke- 
      width:21.5px' /></svg>")

       /* your case hope i adopt it right in this editbox*/ 

       .checkmark{ 
         width = 14px;
         height = 11px;
         color = '#ffffff';

          background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg x="0px" y="0px" width= 
               {width} height={height} viewBox="0 0 38.826 29.541" > <g> 
                <polygon fill={color} points="32.194,0 15.194,17 6.445,8.217 
                0,14.771 
                15.15,29.541 38.826,6.541" /> </g> </svg>");
       }
       </style>
```

or use directly

```
 <IMG class="icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]">

 <div class="logo"></div>
```

And for sure all this can also be done in javascript. Its just up to your design how to show the div or image on your button :)

```
<div className={styles.toggleButton}>
 <!-- sure src="url(..images/image.svg)" works as well -->
 <IMG class="icon" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,[data]"> 
 <input
    id={name}
    type="checkbox"
    className={styles.checkbox}
    value={value}
    checked={value ? 'checked' : null}
    onChange={onChange}
  />
  <label htmlFor={name} className={styles.switch} />
</div>
```

Comment: i edit my answer acc. I would put it in a css rule. This keeps the markup readble and is later on easy to maintain - if you want to change all checkboxes.

Comment: BTW: if you want a nice checkbox - that you can have more easy with a UTF character (Thereis  have a checkmark sign) and a div. Style the div as box and place / stack the checkmark over it. This you can place with the z-index over the ugly Browser boxes. Fontawesome has also such a character - they do this also with svg - There are plenty of ways to de uglyfie checkboxes ;)

Comment: https://www.mediaevent.de/svg-in-html-seiten/ 7 Ways to place svg - sorry its a german page :)

Comment: You own me a beer ;)